# Sorting variable loses value on pagination

Tags: javascript, php

Hello stackoverflow members.

I have a little problem here i have ads site i want to sort ads by recent date, Highest, Lowest price. That works fine when ads are sorted but if pagination links are clicked again ads are sorted by default as recent ads.

```
<select name="Sort_Ads" id="Sort_Ads" onchange="document.getElementById('formName').submit()">
    <option>Most Recent Ads</option>
    <option>Price: High to Low</option>
    <option>Price: Low to High</option>
</select>

if(isset($_POST['Sort_Ads']))
    {   
        $sortit = $_POST['Sort_Ads'];
        if($sortit == "Most Recent Ads") $sort = "ad_id DESC";
        else if($sortit == "Price: Low to High") $sort = "ad_price ASC";
        else if($sortit == "Price: High to Low") $sort = "ad_price DESC";
    }
```

And this my query is  `"SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY $sort $limit"` which works fine.

Only the problem is that sorting is restored on pagination so we only see ads sorted in first page.

And one another thing is that after page refreshes the drop down is set to first option but items are sorted fine. Please any how to set the drop down value as it was before reload page? Because if user click on Sort high to low after page reloaded, the option recent ads will be selected and if he/she want to sort it by recent ads it can't be because its already selected but items are sorted as highest price or what ever option was selected before.

I think it can be done with JavaScript so please i have't enough skills in JavaScript i would be really happy if somebody do this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should remember the sort order in session variable.

Comment: Please any example.. and how to store drop down value till page is reloaded. read it newly added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to remember the sorting order in php session.
Example:

```
$_SESSION['sortorder'] = $sortit;
```

Now you have remembered the sort order in session variable so next step will be:

```
if(isset($_POST['Sort_Ads']))
{   
        $sortit = $_POST['Sort_Ads'];
        $_SESSION['sortorder'] = $sortit;
        if($sortit == "Most Recent Ads") $sort = "ad_id DESC";
        else if($sortit == "Price: Low to High") $sort = "ad_price ASC";
        else if($sortit == "Price: High to Low") $sort = "ad_price DESC";
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['sortorder']))
{   
        $sortit = $_SESSION['sortorder'];
        if($sortit == "Most Recent Ads") $sort = "ad_id DESC";
        else if($sortit == "Price: Low to High") $sort = "ad_price ASC";
        else if($sortit == "Price: High to Low") $sort = "ad_price DESC";
}
```

### Update:


You can remove a specific session variable by:

```
unset($_SESSION['variableName']);
```

OR to remove all the session variables:

```
session_destroy();
```

Now it depends on you that on what condition you want to unset the session variables.

Comment: Worked fine thank you! Bro but i have a last question, I have 2 sessions one display type and another sort and i started session_start(); in the top of page, Now even if user close the website and again enters he see what he was seeing before i mean the sessions all are applied but i don't want if he uses refresh or trying to enter url again so the sessions i want to set it to null then please how :)